# Totaling Expression from group header in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to check our compliance with standards for documenting patient information, using SSRS 2008 R2. For example, in the group header for PatientID, I have `=Not IsNothing(Fields!DATEOFBIRTH.Value)`. Now, I'd like to count the number of patients for which that returns True. The obvious way is

```
=Sum(Iif(Not IsNothing(Fields!DATEOFBIRTH.Value)
        , 1
        , 0
        )
    )
```

(which actually doesn't work, because I have multiple lines per patient, but never mind that for the moment.) The problem is that if I find my logic was wrong, I have to make the correction in two places, and it won't be obvious if I forget. In Crystal, I'd either use a running tally, evaluating on the change of group, or a manual tally with `WhilePrintingRecords;`, having a formula returning the T/F result in both locations. What's the generally-accepted SSRS way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to centralize logic, you can either use custom code in a report or create a custom assembly. With custom code, you'd have to update every report that uses that same logic if you find you need to make  change, but it's simple to add to a report. With a custom assembly, you have to create a class library, compile it and add the code to your machine so BIDS can use it  (and to every developer's machine if applicable) and to the report server. The advantage with the custom assembly is that there is one place to store the logic (not counting the distribution of the DLL) so every report gets updated automatically when you update the logic. This link is a starting point for you and provides links to more details on both of these options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155798(v=sql.100).aspx.